# The files get locked when i upload them to Vsftpd server

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, ubuntu-18.04, vsftpd

I am uploading files to FTP server using spring integration of FTP

```
@Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toFtpChannel")
    public FtpMessageHandler handler() {
        FtpMessageHandler handler = new FtpMessageHandler(ftpSessionFactory());
        handler.setChmod(0600);
        handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(new LiteralExpression("./Documents"));
        return handler;
    }

    @MessagingGateway
    public interface MyGateway {

        @Gateway(requestChannel = "toFtpChannel")
        void sendToFtp(File file);

    }
```

First, I tried to upload the files by setting the Chmod of the handler to 
0600 but I get the below error.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: chmod operations not supported

Is there a way to upload the files and make them readable and writable. and also, do I need to create a file in my local Disk to upload it to the server or is there a way for me to create and edit a file directly in the Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to read write directly on server using any ftp client like `filezilla` :

---

You can change the ownership of the ftp folder to ftp user using the following command after sshing to your server using root:

```
chown -R ftpuser /var/www/html/uploadfolder/
```

here, ftpuser is just an example. You should use your own ftp user. You can level up and could give ownership in html directory too.

```
chown -R ftpuser /var/www/html/
```

Comment: I did that, but still when i upload the file, it gets locked automatically.

Comment: after changing the ownership you should be able to edit, delete the already uploaded files as you (the ftp user) have the ownership now. It works from me, what group your uploaded files get when uploaded?

Comment: when i see the properties of the file i see this, Group:ftpuser and Access:Read-only

Comment: also is there a way to create and edit a file directly into the server, without having to create it locally and then edit and upload it?

Comment: Are you using any ftp client like filezilla or something else? In filezilla you could right click on the folder and assign write access from the permission context menu.

Comment: i think i fixed it, thank you, but is there a difference between 550 and 553 errors? please do answer and also my above question of create and edit?

Comment: You can find this useful : https://kb.globalscape.com/KnowledgebaseArticle10142.aspx